# Use eslint-config-airbnb without react plugins

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I want to use the airbnb's eslinter without installing any react plugins. Is that possible?

Basically, all I want is to use this: [eslint-config-airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb).
But it seems that it comes bundled with some react specific stuff, as it requires:

> It requires eslint, eslint-plugin-import, eslint-plugin-react, and eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y.

If I don't separately install those other plugins, my Atom editor will complain:

> Error: Failed to load plugin react: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react' Referenced from: airbnb Referenced from: /../../.eslintrc

So how can I use the eslint-config-airbnb without those react plugins? (Since I won't be using react).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't care for the react rules, your best bet would be to use [eslint-config-airbnb-base](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base) instead.